# Volley request timeout using Futures

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

I want to create a synchronous request to a REST service using Volley library.
I tried to setup an "Helper" to manage the request using Future object and a 15s timeout, this is my code:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.OperationApplicationException;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class RestHelper {

    private static RestHelper instance = null;
    private static String L="LOG";

    public static synchronized RestHelper getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (null == instance)
            instance = new RestHelper(context);
        return instance;
    }

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private RestHelper(Context context)
    {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }


    private JsonElement get(String url) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, future, future);
        requestQueue.add(request);
        JSONObject obj;
        try{
            obj=future.get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e){
            if(e.getCause() instanceof VolleyError) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = ((VolleyError) e.getCause()).networkResponse;
                Log.e(L,"Network error, HTTP status: "+networkResponse.statusCode);
                Log.e(L,"Network error, HTTP content: "+new String(networkResponse.data));
            }else
                Log.e(L,"Network error: "+e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }catch (TimeoutException e){
            Log.e(L,"Network timeout");
            throw e;
        }
        return parseResponse(obj);
    }

    private JsonElement parseResponse(JSONObject obj){
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement mJson =  parser.parse(obj.toString());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Return ret = gson.fromJson(mJson, Return.class);
        if(!ret.isSuccess())
            throw new RuntimeException(ret.getError());
        return mJson;
    }
}
```

The remote endpoint is called (I have found the connection log on remote server), but the future object is always discaderd for timeout.

I have read something about a Thread problem, but as far as I know the `RequestQueue` is made using the main appliaction context. Is it enought? What else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `startQueue`? From your code you don't have it.

Based on [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue).

```
// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

// Start the queue
requestQueue.start();
```

Comment: `Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext())` doesn't start the queue?

Comment: @Tobia It's. Just wired for different creation instance of `RequestQueue` there is different doc.

Comment: I tried but It doesn't change. The future is still in timeout. ... :-(